# Execute PHP code by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

I want to execute some PHP code by clicking on a link

**HTML:**

```
<a style='text-align: right;cursor:pointer;' href="#" name="reset" class='system list-group-item'>
    <span style="float: left;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Client reset
</a>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_GET['reset'])){
    $link=$_GET['reset'];
        if ($link == '1') {
           do something
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried many ways and the best way is an onClick event that starts a ajax call.
Like this:

HTML:

```
<a style='text-align: right;cursor:pointer;' onclick="reset();" name="reset" class='system list-group-item'>
            <span style="float: left;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Client zur&uuml;cksetzten</a>
```

JS:

```
  function reset() {
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'index.php',
       data:{method : 'resetClient'},
       success:function(html) {
         swal({   title: "Success!",   text: "Client has been reset.",   type: "success",   confirmButtonText: "Ok", confirmButtonColor: "#c9132a" });
       }
  }); }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: just chnage the href attribute of you link to something like `href="?reset=true"`

Comment: This code doesn't works, i want to know how to do that

Comment: @Dale thanks i'll try that! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your current URL is `index.php`

**HTML**

```
<a style='text-align: right;cursor:pointer;' href="index.php?reset=true" name="reset" class='system list-group-item'>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['reset'])) {
    myFunction();
  }
function myFunction() {
//do something
}
?>
```

Comment: Its enough to just put `?reset=true` in the `href`, the `index.php` part isn't necessary.

Comment: yeah that also will work.. I just wanted to convey the full format, so that he can use the same technique to access the functions in some other pages also..

Comment: Worked fine thanks for answer! :D

Comment: you are always welcome.. :) keep using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass some value while submitting  the form so that you can check whether it is a submitted or un submitted form . in my code i passed  reset=1.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['reset']))// is to check whether reset is present or not. if it present then the condition is satisfied and executed 
{
$link=$_GET['reset'];
if ($link == '1'){
echo "success";
}
}
?>
<html>
<a style='text-align: right;cursor:pointer;' href="?reset=1" name="reset"  class='system list-group-item'>
    <span style="float: left;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">    </span>Client reset</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

HTML:

```
<a style='text-align: right;cursor:pointer;' href="?reset=1" class='system list-group-item'>
            <span style="float: left;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Client reset</a>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['reset'])){
$link=$_GET['reset'];
    if ($link == '1'){
     do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value after the hash mark or anchor (#) as shown in a user's browser: This isn't possible with "standard" HTTP as this value is never sent to the server (it won't be available in $_GET["reset"] or similar predefined variables). You would need some JavaScript magic on the client side.

[Rajesh kannan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33753845/4193971)'s answer is the best way to get around this.

Comment: @Valcone JavaScript magic.